# login window opend in right monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I have a dual monitor system (set as extended) and my problem is when I log into an application, it opens a login window in the right monitor and only after that it displays the application's window in the left (main) monitor. Is there any way to make that app open the login window in the left display?

Edit:
The application is a software I use at work and it is used only there.

Comment: What 'app' or 'apps' are you referring to specifically? Just a couple examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but perhaps your app uses monitor 1, but your primary monitor is number 2. This is arguably a bug in your app. You could try change the numbering. If you have 'Notebook + Screen and Screen + Notebook alternatives, you could try those.